# How do I access every single word in a file java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

I am trying to keep every single word in this file into an array so i could apply my own language implementation on it. I have applied split already but when I put the string into the variable parts, `parts[0]` will display the whole file instead of one word only while `parts[1]` will give an error

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

How do I access every single word in this file?

```
String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
System.out.print(parts[0] + '\n');
```

file test.snol contains

```
SNOL
INTO num IS 5
INTO res IS MULT num num
INTO res IS MULT res res
INTO res IS MOD res num
PRINT num
PRINT res
LONS
```

Comment: how do you read the file?

Comment: I think your regex is wrong. You want a backslash, not forward slash. Try `line.split("\\s+");`

Comment: file test.snol contains

SNOL INTO num IS 5 INTO res IS MULT num num INTO res IS MULT res res INTO res IS MOD res num PRINT num PRINT res LONS

Comment: I wanted to edit the file and put spaces but it's basically a text file which contains codes and the lines are separated by spaces.

Comment: @ElanHamburger the output of System.out.print(parts[0] + '\n'); changed but it just displays the first word of every line.

Comment: @Robyyyn Correct, the line got split up into an array. `parts[1]` will contain the second word, `parts[2]` the third word, etc.

Comment: @ElanHamburger there is an error  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 at parts[1] and parts[2]

Comment: @Robyyyn because your first line only contains one word. You need to check the length of the array after each `split` and handle appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using java-8 you can do so in a single line :-

```
String[] words = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH))
                      .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")))
                      .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Alternatively, if you want to access each line as a `list` of `String[]` you can use :-

```
List<String[]> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
                            .stream().map(e -> e.split(" "))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression match token for whitespace is `\s`. Your code uses a forward slash (`/`) instead of a backslash (`\`) which has no special meaning, so your code is trying to match two forward slashes followed by one or more `s`s.

In Java, regular expressions are passed through strings, so backslashes need to be escaped by a second backslash (unlike a forward slash which needs no special handling). Your regular expression should read `"\\s+"` which will match one more whitespace characters.

Your call to `split` should then return an array with each word from the line as a different element.

If you are reading your file line by line, you can access every word with code like

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.snol"));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
    for (String word : words) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: why does it have an error on for (String line : lines)
it says here that the symbol cannot be found

Comment: Because you need to provide it with the lines from your file. You didn't say how you read the file, so I can't help you.

Comment: public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

        //Open this file.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\test.snol"));
        
        // Read lines from file.
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }